# scayt security in CKEDitor

Tags: ckeditor, scayt

I work on a WYSIWYG plugin for DokuWiki that uses the CKEditor. It's been  in use since FCKeditor days, and no one has ever raised any security before. But a user recently raised the question as to whether the Scayt spell checker was a security risk because of how it is implemented, i.e. passing textin parameters from the wiki to the Scayt servers in order to check spelling. On a public wiki this would not matter.  But when a wiki is closed, internal to a company or on a personal LAN, does this potentially open up the closed wiki to a third party?  I would appreciate any information or views.

For the complete exchange of views on this topic see: https://github.com/turnermm/ckgedit/issues/434

Comment: I have replied in https://github.com/turnermm/ckgedit/issues/434 directly. Basically it is safe but if someone doesn't like the idea of his data being sent to remote services, he can use SCAYT on his dedicated server. It should be possible to switch licenses provided that DokuWiki plugins allows its users to modify editor instance freely (this is where SCAYT configuration can be set).